# IBM Script Portlet for WebSphere Portal 7

Tags: java, portlet, websphere-portal

Anyone knows if Script Portlet can be used for WebSphere Portal 7?

I noticed that Portlet exists for IBM/HCL WP 8.5 but cant find for WP 7.

The goal is to add some html/css to some pages but cant find the right way to it and it seems the Script Portlet is just what I need.

I'm limited to WebSphere Portal 7 version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Not sure if Script Portlet runs on WP7. I remember it was kind of a novelty of WP8 (or 8.5).
2. Script Portlet is a fancy wrapper for the old Authoring Template/Presentation Template/Web Content Viewer Portlet flow. It does add some functionality like importing a ZIP file which then explodes into multiple fields of a WCM Content, but the basic storing/rendering flow remains the same.
3. That said, if you just need to add some inline CSS/HTML to specific pages, you could just rely on the basics of WCM/Portal and: A) Create an AT with an HTML field, B) Pair it with a PT that renders that field, C) Create WCM Content based on the previously created AT and insert the code to insert on the pages, D) On the Portal page add Web Content Viewer Portlet instance, go to "Edit Shared Settings" and configure the portlet to point to the WCM Content you just created.